# Pivot on specific columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I would like to apply a type of pivot on a pandas dataframe but I can't find the proper way to do it.

What I want to do:

`input_df`:

```
p_id p_name prod_t1 prod_t2 prod_t3
-----------------------------------
1    foo    3       2       4
2    bar    0       1       0
```

`expected_output_df`:

```
p_id p_name prod_time quantity
-----------------------------------
1    foo    prod_t1   3
1    foo    prod_t2   2
1    foo    prod_t3   4
2    bar    prod_t1   0
2    bar    prod_t2   1
2    bar    prod_t3   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is melt:

```
df.melt(id_vars=['p_id','p_name'],
        var_name='prod_time', 
        value_name='quantity')
```

Output:

```
   p_id p_name prod_time  quantity
0     1    foo   prod_t1         3
1     2    bar   prod_t1         0
2     1    foo   prod_t2         2
3     2    bar   prod_t2         1
4     1    foo   prod_t3         4
5     2    bar   prod_t3         0
```

Or this can be `stack`:

```
(df.set_index(['p_id','p_name'])
   .stack().reset_index()
   .rename(columns={'level_2':'prod_time', 0:'quantity'})
)
```

Output:

```
   p_id p_name prod_time  quantity
0     1    foo   prod_t1         3
1     1    foo   prod_t2         2
2     1    foo   prod_t3         4
3     2    bar   prod_t1         0
4     2    bar   prod_t2         1
5     2    bar   prod_t3         0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.melt(id_vars = ['p_name'], value_vars= ['prod_t1', 'prod_t2', 'prod_t3'])

>>>

    p_name  variable    value
0   foo     prod_t1     3
1   bar     prod_t1     0
2   foo     prod_t2     2
3   bar     prod_t2     1
4   foo     prod_t3     4
5   bar     prod_t3     0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to do `wide_to_long`, notice the order here

```
df=pd.wide_to_long(df,['prod'],
                   i=['p_id','p_name'],
                   j='Number',
                   suffix='\w+',sep='_').reset_index()
   p_id p_name Number  prod
0     1    foo     t1     3
1     1    foo     t2     2
2     1    foo     t3     4
3     2    bar     t1     0
4     2    bar     t2     1
5     2    bar     t3     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completion, this is solution using `stack`

```
(df.set_index(['p_id', 'p_name']).rename_axis('prod_time', axis=1)
                                 .stack().reset_index(name='quantity'))

Out[1103]:
   p_id p_name prod_time  quantity
0     1    foo   prod_t1         3
1     1    foo   prod_t2         2
2     1    foo   prod_t3         4
3     2    bar   prod_t1         0
4     2    bar   prod_t2         1
5     2    bar   prod_t3         0
```